# Native debugger crash: Bad file descriptor

Tags: android, debugging

I'm trying to debug C++ Native code in an Android project, but, after days trying to set the debugger, 
I've got this strange, and really exasperating error message thrown by gdb:

Remote connection error: bad file descriptor.

I searched on internet for people who had the same error. There is a few, but none the resolved their problem...

This is, in detail, how I did to set my Android project:

- I downloaded and installed the JDK on my computer, and set the JAVA_HOME Variable
- Downloaded the latest android ndk (r8), the latest android sdk
- Installed cygwin, with c++, gcc, gdb, make...
- Installed eclipse Indigo for Java developpers, and the following packages: CDT, ADT, Sequoyah

I created a new android project, added native support, and set in the .mk file the following lines
(I think some of these lines could have been removed, but I wanted to be sure...):

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_CFLAGS    := -Wall -Werror -DANDROID_NDK -g
LOCAL_CPPFLAGS  := -Wall -Werror -DANDROID_NDK -g
LOCAL_LDLIBS    := -lm -llog -g -ggdb -O1
APP_OPTIM   := debug
LOCAL_MODULE    := native
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := native.cpp
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

I added a new builder in Project->Properties->Builders->New->Program:

```
- Location: selection the ndk-build program, in your NDK directory
- Working Directory: Select the jni folder in your solution
```

I removed the command line in Project->Properties->C/C++ Build, in order to avoid error messages generated by calling the make command

I added the path to the android ndk includes (ANDROID_NDK_ROOT\platforms\android-14\arch-arm\usr\include) in the "C/C++ General" section, for both GNU C and GNU C++ sections

I created a new "C/C++ Application" debugger, with:
    "Using Standard Create Process Launcher" selected

```
in the "Main" tab   

PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT\obj\local\armeabi\app_process in the "C/C++ Application" field
Name of my project in the "Project" field
```

I set the build configuration to default.

in the "Debugger" tab

```
    gdbserver in the debugger combobox

in the main subtab:

    GDB Debugger field:     PATH_TO_NDK/toolchains/arm-linux-androideabi-4.4.3/prebuilt/windows/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb.exe
    GDB Command file:   PATH_TO_MY_PROJECT/obj/local/armeabi/gdb2.setup (I copied gdb.setup in gdb2.setup, and removed the last line as explained in most tutorials on the internet)

in the connection subtab:   
Type: TCP 
Host name: localhost
Port number: 5039 (the same as the one used by ndk-gdb)
```

I added the android:debuggable="true" line in the manifest (in addition with all the debugging flags in the .mk file)

Sorry for this long explanation, but this will give you a complete idea about my configuration.
I may have made some other settings, but I think the most important ones are explained here.
I'm on windows 7 64, and I tried on multiple devices (emulator, acer/asus tablets, htc smartphones...), some of them rooted, but it still crash.

I Hope someone will be able to help me, I have to port an entire project to android...

And if someone put this debugger to work, I'll be glad to learn about your configuration!

Thanks in advance =)

Comment: Because I've had to do so on non-Android platforms without automated scripts, I'd be tempted to look up and run through the steps of starting up the remote gdb session by hand from the host and adb shell command lines, and get an idea of where it is failing.  Is there any indication, from the screen or 'ps' in the adb shell that the app & gdb remote even get started?